Equivalence proof between sum and integral
Given the following sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \log_2(i)$$
I want to find a closed form for it, or at least the term of greatest asymptotic growth of its outcome. However, to simplify such procedure, I computed the integral of the summand expression:
$$\int_1^n \log _2(i) \, di=\frac{n (\log (n)-1)}{\log (2)}$$
Then, to verify the correctness of the result, I need to prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \log_2(i)\sim\int_1^n \log _2(i) \, di$$
But, I don't know how to proceed with such task.

Oh, well these two facts should be sufficient to prove your claim: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\log n = \infty,\ $ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\log n - \int_{n-1}^{n}\log x dx\right)=0.$

$\sum\log_2i=\log_2i!$. Now use Sterling's estimate for factorial.

There's a nice family of factorial approximations at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2012.11.023 Here's a quick log factorial demo: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNjztuwzAQRHueYgAX4ioyP2vESAzoFGnTMIkkr2GTBMWCxw%5FMIkg3b4r5HHBPG9bwXVORcEfIuaQmj1AlRXXAx7LgWmveL9b%2DJDGpbNY7450%5F25u5PUIw7Dwb743jk1JfUnfMeHNKrawbYX4WaB6zjI0s44iGFzSM3Vfo6K32PDYcu3Jd8en8bjW%5F8tiIiJRaU4FAIvYS4rZonsCOLgpALhKrlqln%5Fp3RQmSifk6iCStr%2DYfDMGFf8jx8xoGU%2DgUjd0de&lang=sage

Do you know about Riemann sums?
It's the fact that for many functions $f$, in the sense of taking the limit as $n\rightarrow +\infty$
$$\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1} f\left( \frac k n\right) \sim \int_0^1 f(x)dx$$
Apply this to $f=\ln_2$ and you obtain
$$\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1} \ln_2\left( \frac k n\right) \sim \int_0^1 \ln_2(x)dx=-\frac 1 {\log 2} $$
Using the fact that $\ln_2\left(\frac k n\right) = \ln_2 k - \ln_2 n$, and expanding the left-hand side:
$$\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n \ln_2(k)\sim \ln_2(n)-\frac 1 {\log 2} $$
This confirms your result:
$$\boxed{\sum_{k=1}^n \ln_2(k)\sim n\cdot\frac{\log(n)-1} {\log 2} }$$
